# How to check whether data in the list contains 0 or null value and remove that data

Tags: java

Following is the code that i have created till now.
That is the program below is reading the file and if one of the field in the given file is empty then it is printing `0` for integer value and `null` for string value.

```
// Override all the methods of the DataManager Interface
public class StudentDataManager implements DataManager {
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public List<Student> populateData(String fileName) {

        Scanner s = null;
        String nameAndRollNumber = "";
        String numbers[] = null;
        Integer roll1 = 0;
        String roll = null;
        String name = null;
        String age = null;
        String zip = null;
        String street = null;
        String city = null;
        Integer age1 = 0;
        String cpmletedata = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("F:\\...\\StudentDetails.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            nameAndRollNumber = s.nextLine();
            String[] nameAndRollNumbers = nameAndRollNumber.split(",");
            try {
                roll = nameAndRollNumbers[0];
                roll1 = Integer.valueOf(roll);
                cpmletedata = " " + roll;
                name = nameAndRollNumbers[1];

                if (nameAndRollNumbers[1].equals("")) {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " null ";
                } else {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " " + name;
                }

                age = nameAndRollNumbers[2];

                if (nameAndRollNumbers[2].equals("")) {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " 0 ";
                } else {
                    age1 = Integer.valueOf(age);
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " " + age1;
                }

                street = nameAndRollNumbers[3];
                if (nameAndRollNumbers[3].equals("")) {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " null ";
                } else {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " " + street;
                }

                city = nameAndRollNumbers[4];
                if (nameAndRollNumbers[4].equals("")) {
                    // System.out.print("null");
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " null ";
                } else {
                    // System.out.print(city + " ");
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " " + city;
                }

                zip = nameAndRollNumbers[5];

                if (nameAndRollNumbers[5].equals(" ")) {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " null ";
                } else {
                    cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " " + zip;
                }

                Address a1 = new Address(street, city, zip);
                cpmletedata = cpmletedata + " ";
                System.out.println(cpmletedata);
                list.add(new Student(roll1, name, age1, a1));
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        s.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Right now I am having this much code which gives the following output:

```
 1 Arjun 12 GhandiNagar Pune 411020 
 2 Deep 8 M.G.Road Mumbai 411032 
 3 Deep 3 F.C.Road Pune 411032 
 4 Neha 10 Camp Pune 411023 
 5 Seema 0  null  null  null  
 6 Bani 6 Camp Mumbai 411045 
 7 Deepali 3 M.G.Road Mumbai 411032 
 8 Neha 0  null  Mumbai null  
 9 Meena 9 Nariman Point Mumbai 411045 
 10 Chaitali 3 M.G.Road Mumbai 411032 
 11 Bani 6 Camp Mumbai 411045 
 12 Deepali 3 M.G.Road Mumbai 411032 
 13 Neha 10 F.C. Road Pune 411023 
 14 Deep 3 F.C.Road Pune 411032 
 15 Beena 6 Camp Mumbai 411045
```

The another function is there to validate the data. I.e now if the record contains `0` or `null` we have to invalidate it, i.e we have to to remove that particular row and throw the exception as `InsufficientDataException`. I have created that exception but I am not getting that. How to read that list again and check whether row contains `0` or `null` and validate it?

Comment: @xavy Please help me with it.

Comment: iterate your list with for/while loop, check it if it id equal to null or 0 , if it is equal remove the element from list..

Comment: when i tried to print list [com.psl.beans.Student@173a10f, com.psl.beans.Student@530daa, com.psl.beans.Student@a62fc3, com.psl.beans.Student@89ae9e, com.psl.beans.Student@1270b73, com.psl.beans.Student@60aeb0, com.psl.beans.Student@16caf43, com.psl.beans.Student@66848c, com.psl.beans.Student@8813f2, com.psl.beans.Student@1d58aae, com.psl.beans.Student@83cc67, com.psl.beans.Student@e09713, com.psl.beans.Student@de6f34, com.psl.beans.Student@156ee8e, com.psl.beans.Student@47b480]
 it is not giving the right output. Output is

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution and a suggestion from my side is to use `CollectionUtils` from `org.apache.commons`:

```
List<Student> lAllStudent = lStudentDataManager.populateData("testfile.txt");
int lOldSize = lAllStudent.size();
CollectionUtils.filter(lAllStudent, new ListSelector<Student>() {

  @Override
  public boolean select(int pIndex, Student pInput) {
    if (pInput.getAge()==0 || pInput.getZip() == null || pInput.getStreet() == null || pInput.getCity() == null){
      return false;  
    }
    return true;
  }
});
if (lOldSize != lAllStudent.size()){
  throw new InsufficientDataException();
}
```

if `select` returns `false` the element is removed from the list.
After the `filter` was invoked you can compare the old size of the list with the new one. If there is a difference between the current and the old size, some elements were removed and you can throw your `exception`.

Comment: The problem i am getting is while accessing that list. If we only print the list it is giving output as [com.psl.beans.Student@69b332, com.psl.beans.Student@173a10f, com.psl.beans.Student@530daa, com.psl.beans.Student@a62fc3, com.psl.beans.Student@89ae9e, com.psl.beans.Student@1270b73, com.psl.beans.Student@60aeb0, com.psl.beans.Student@16caf43, com.psl.beans.Student@66848c, com.psl.beans.Student@8813f2, com.psl.beans.Student@1d58aae, com.psl.beans.Student@83cc67, com.psl.beans.Student@e09713, com.psl.beans.Student@de6f34, com.psl.beans.Student@156ee8e] –

Comment: what could be the problem? I am new in java please help me with it

Comment: you have to overwrite the toString method of the Student class

Comment: what is not working? Filtering, Output? edit your question with your current code.

Comment: I am just printing  String s1=list.toString();
  System.out.println(s1);
  return list;  after catch but output it prints is [com.psl.beans.Student@173a10f, com.psl.beans.Student@530daa, com.psl.beans.Student@a62fc3, com.psl.beans.Student@89ae9e, com.psl.beans.Student@1270b73, com.psl.beans.Student@60aeb0, com.psl.beans.Student@16caf43, com.psl.beans.Student@66848c, com.psl.beans.Student@8813f2, com.psl.beans.Student@1d58aae, com.psl.beans.Student@83cc67, com.psl.beans.Student@e09713, com.psl.beans.Student@de6f34, com.psl.beans.Student@156ee8e, com.psl.beans.Student@47b480]

Comment: and you overwrite the toString method? what you see here is the string representation of your object. if you dont overwrite the toString thats ok.

Comment: Overriding method worked.. sorry new in java so took time.. Thank you for your help

Comment: you know how this is done? click on the white hook top left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validate() : boolean method that read each entry of the array and test if there is a 0 or a null value. If it detects this case it return false, else at the end of the method you return true.

Comment: The problem i am getting is while accessing that list. If we only print the list  it is giving output as [com.psl.beans.Student@69b332, com.psl.beans.Student@173a10f, com.psl.beans.Student@530daa, com.psl.beans.Student@a62fc3, com.psl.beans.Student@89ae9e, com.psl.beans.Student@1270b73, com.psl.beans.Student@60aeb0, com.psl.beans.Student@16caf43, com.psl.beans.Student@66848c, com.psl.beans.Student@8813f2, com.psl.beans.Student@1d58aae, com.psl.beans.Student@83cc67, com.psl.beans.Student@e09713, com.psl.beans.Student@de6f34, com.psl.beans.Student@156ee8e]

Comment: what could be the problem? I am new in java please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the current StudentList then it will throw an exception,
So creating another studentList with a condition of selecting only desired 
entries will be a good approach, Like this :

---

```
public void validateData(List<Student> studentList)
        throws InsufficientDataException {
    List<Student> studentList2 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    // studentList2.addAll(studentList);

    int i = 0;
    for (Student s : studentList) {

        i++;
        if ((s.getRollno() == 0) || (s.getStudentName() == "null")
                || (s.getAge() == 0)
                || (s.getAddress().getStreetName() == "null")
                || (s.getAddress().getCity() == "null")
                || (s.getAddress().getZipCode() == "null")) {
        } else {
            studentList2.add(s);
        }
    }

    for (Student s : studentList2) {
        System.out.println(s.getRollno() + "  " + s.getStudentName() + "  "
                + s.getAge() + "  " + s.getAddress().getStreetName() + "  "
                + s.getAddress().getCity() + "  "
                + s.getAddress().getZipCode());
    }

}
```

and so here is your desired output (filtered) :

---

```
1  Arjun  12  GhandiNagar  Pune  411020
2  Deep  8  M.G.Road  Mumbai  411032
3  Deep  3  F.C.Road  Pune  411032
4  Neha  10  Camp  Pune  411023
6  Bani  6  Camp  Mumbai  411045
7  Deepali  3  M.G.Road  Mumbai  411032
9  Meena  9  Nariman Point  Mumbai  411045
10  Chaitali  3  M.G.Road  Mumbai  411032
11  Bani  6  Camp  Mumbai  411045
12  Deepali  3  M.G.Road  Mumbai  411032
13  Neha  10  F.C. Road  Pune  411023
14  Deep  3  F.C.Road  Pune  411032
15  Beena  6  Camp  Mumbai  411045
```