# how to remove particular row from generic list

Tags: java

I have this method. I want to remove the row from the list that contains 0 or null value where the values in the list are as follow

```
rollno name age city street zipcode
1       abc  0  pqr   xyz   145202
```

as age has value as zero, we have to remove it. Can any body plz help me with it I am new in java?

In following code I am removing the row and  i am again printing list

```
public void validateData(List<Student> studentList) throws InsufficientDataException {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(list));
    for (Iterator < Student > iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Student a = iter.next();
        if (list.contains("null")) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: What is the code for `Student`? Is it a bean with attributes `rollno`, `name`, `age`, `city`, `street` and `zipcode`?

Comment: already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112429/how-to-check-whether-data-in-the-list-contains-0-or-null-value-and-remove-that-d/31112972#31112972

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fields of Student class are public and your list can contain nulls.

```
public void validateData (List<Student> studentList) throws InsufficientDataException {
        for (Iterator<Student> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Student a = iter.next();
            if (a == null) { // Check if a is null
                iter.remove(); // remove it because it is null

            } else {// a is not null
                if (a.age == 0) { // check if age is 0
                    iter.remove(); //Remove it because age is 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The variable 'a' which you get from the iterator is the element of the list which you get at every iteration. You need to check whether the variable is null or if it contains a student with age 0, rather than checking whether the list contain null.

```
 if (list.contains("null")) { //This is wrong.
      iter.remove();
 }
```

In the end I will strongly recommend you to read Javadocs on Lists

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html